# Access crashes after splitting when running some (not all) queries

Tags: ms-access

My database (Access 2016) was running fine but I needed to split it to separate the front end from the data tables.

After splitting I find that running one of my larger queries causes Access to simply close without any prompt and to create an orphan lock file for the back end file.  This large query is built using many smaller sub queries.

Are there any common issues that arise from splitting a DB that could cause issues like this?

This is repeatable with the same large query, and I have tried re-splitting the database from my backup.  Same issue.

All the sub queries of the large query run ok on their own.  I have systematically removed one sub query at a time to identify which ones are causing the problem.

I found that removing EITHER 1 sub query (call it sq1) OR removing 2 other sub queries (sq2 and sq3) fixed the problem.  In each case the join is to show all the records from the large query and only the matching records in the sub queries.  I need to remove EITHER sq1 OR both sq2 and sq3 to make the large query work.

As I say, all 3 sub queries run Ok on their own, but when run as sub queries they cause the large query to cause Access to close.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the timings? I mean... how long take the queries separately in the original configuration and after the splitting?

Comment: Please share that query, as one solution is to optimize it. On the other hand, do you have both files on the same hard drive? are you using mapped network drive? It could be timeout issue due to network latency

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are are executing your query over slow network. If this is the case, here are some proposed solutions

1. Check Windows Event Logs to see if there is an error logged with more info about the crash root cause.
2. Put both files (back-end and front-end) on the same local machine. If this is not valid for your business case, at least it will help you identify the root cause
3. Optimize the query to enhance its execution plan and accordingly minimize execution time. (this depends on how the current query is written and if there is anything to improve)
4. Move the query to the back-end and make the front-end logic just displays the result

Also, It could be something wrong happened during splitting, you can try a different way as follows

1. Import forms, queries, macros, etc from your current original file (the single file containing both back-end and front-end)
2. From Linked Table manager, create links to your current tables on the original files

Comment: It is a horrendously complex query so I am sure that is a factor.  I am not using a network, both front and backend are on my laptop.

Comment: I found a workaround by deleting sq1 and then creating a new query with the old large query as the main input and then added sq1.  It works, but as outlined in my more recent new post, my VBA script in MS Project which references this query in Access is now very very slow.

Comment: I'm reluctant to try to simplify the query as it is the basis of much of how my database works.  I was mainly hoping for a pointer as to why splitting the DB has caused what worked previously to stop working, especially given no network is involved.

Comment: Have you tried to split the Access file the way I explained? as it could be an issue in the splitting wizard

Comment: Gouda - I have not tried your suggestion yet.  I have a lot of tables and am not sure how much effort is involved in re-linking, and am not sure this will fix the issue.  As I have a workaround (described above) I am focusing on a different problem right now, but thanks for the input.  I'll report back if I find a different solution or do as you suggested.